# Linux HomeBrew root user issues

Tags: linux, homebrew

I am new at Linux and I installed the HomeBrew to intall git, docker and so on... What I notice that has hapenned to me is... I install HomeBrew and some of what I mentioned before, the deal is that once I change the user to root and try to run any brew comman I get the following error:

[termianl image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRC1h.png)

After this the brew doesnt even work in my user... I do not know how to fix this neither why this happens.

Has anyone ever had a problem like this before?

I was told by someone in stackoverflow that I shouldn be using homebrew on linux, is that accurate?

Comment: The general recommendation is **not** to run `brew` as root, but instead add your user account to a group that has write permissions on `/usr/local`. From your description it's impossible to figure out what got messed up on your system, so I don't think you can get it repaired in stackexchange's Q&A format.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for explaining, I am going to do exactly what you instructed!